# Can I get Stalker/Gustraag 3/Harvester to spawn if I go AFK?

Tags: warframe

While I have been farming for the Brakk, it has gotten very tedious to do missions. Can I AFK for a bit (the time it takes till they don't spawn anymore), and have them spawn in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word of advice: DONT.

Under no circumstances should you ever "afk" to get those secret bosses to spawn in.  Especially the Grustag 3, which are extremely deadly against a whole team of players, it is not advisable to AFK, because you may get killed while waiting for them to spawn.

That said, if your question is about waiting in spawn and waiting for them to spawn, that works perfectly too as well.  From what I've seen, I haven't seen a concrete time they spawn.  I've had Harvesters spawn towards the near-ends of survival missions.  I've had the Grustag 3 give me a surprise party after walking out of spawn (after flickerling lights and such).  Hell, I've even had the Stalker show up after AFK'ing (I left my computer, and when I got back, I was dead, and the Stalker left some message)

Comment: By AFK, I mean by playing on my 3DS or Phone while paying attention to my game. I do not know about the Gustrag 3 or the Harvester, but the Wiki states that the Stalker will spawn between 30s-4min (not 100% sure).

Comment: Ill try AFKing, and when I get one that works, ill give you the accept.

Answer (score 2):

Yea you can. As long as you have a pro group going every1 can afk as long as every1 stays in earshot of their computers.  The lotus always warns you they are coming so just listen for that.  I usually just alt tab and read something with my headphones on. Wait 4 mins rinse repeat.